# How to receive the driving start and stop activity with Android in an energy efficient manner?

Tags: mobile

I would like to receive the Android location call backs for Driving Start and Stop. I have tried the Activity Detection API by Google but it doesn't seem to be reliable enough. As well as, I have looked into using Neura's API to detect the location events but it only works when the device is online which is not sufficient in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use google's FenceApi in order to declare a driving fence.

Though this approach seems good, i've faced with the fact that this api didn't tell me sometimes when user starts/finishes driving, and sometimes it took a long time after i started driving that the api told me of that event.